# How to remove these duplicates?

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

I have the following fields in a file, I want the remove the duplicates based on first four fields.

I have used SUM FIELDS for First four fields but I didn't get the desired output.

```
  1   1   1     12.01.2015  21   1
  1   1   1     12.01.2015  22   1
  1   1   1     12.01.2015  23   1

  1   1   1     12.01.2015  24   2
  1   1   1     12.01.2015  25   2
  1   1   1     12.01.2015  26   2
```

My output should be like

```
   1   1   1     12.01.2015  21   1
   1   1   1     12.01.2015  22   1
   1   1   1     12.01.2015  23   1
```

My point is like first three Fields should be considered a one Record and next three as one record. How can I achieve it in JCL?

Comment: If you use the first four fields, your sample only has one key. Can you explain that last paragraph. JCL can do you nothing. Are you using DFSORT or SyncSORT? What is the code you tried? Please update your question with all this information. Although the data looks interesting, I doubt the "upvoter" noticed that. Suspicious. Please ask your friends not to vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

With your data:

```
  OPTION COPY 
  INCLUDE COND=(34,1,CH,EQ,C'1')
```

Will get you the output you want.

JCL simply arranges the resources for a program to run, and what happens before and after that. It is programs which do the work. JCL can do nothing on its own.